# Slow download speeds on OpenVPN. Configuration issue?

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, openvpn

Trying to determine why OpenVPN was pulling 1mbps down. The server has a dedicated 1gbps connection so I am sure the server can't be the bottleneck. I just started playing around with tls-crypt and was curious if trying to do this to make traffic look like HTTPS/TLS is the issue.

I reduced all the encryption to the minimum to see if that was the issue.

CLIENT:

```
client
proto tcp-client
remote IP 443
dev tun
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
verify-x509-name server_ICbcwWyFekPWtXQk name
auth SHA256
auth-nocache
cipher AES-128-CBC
tls-client
compress lz4
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256
setenv opt block-outside-dns
verb 3
<ca>
</ca>
<cert>
</cert>
<key>
</key>
key-direction 1
<tls-crypt>
</tls-crypt>
```

SERVER:

```
port 443
proto tcp
dev tun
user nobody
group nobody
persist-key
persist-tun
keepalive 10 120
topology subnet
compress lz4-v2
push "compress lz4-v2"
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "dhcp-option DNS 1.1.1.1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
crl-verify crl.pem
ca ca.crt
cert server_ICbcwWyFekPWtXQk.crt
key server_ICbcwWyFekPWtXQk.key
tls-crypt tls-auth.key 0
dh dh.pem
auth SHA256
cipher AES-128-CBC
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256
status /var/log/openvpn/status.log
verb 3
```

Comment: You may find some hints [here](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Gigabit_Networks_Linux).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you openvpn server had a **really low** performance CPU I do not think issue is encryption or compression related.

Your server is served by a gigabit connection, great! But also the clients? If you get on both side a fix IP (can also be done with dynamic IP) can test connection without the openvpn tunnel using iperf, like this you can exclude the internet connection form the equation.
For improve the performance you could try also to play with the MTU of the tunnel and the compression method, can give a bit help.